# Summing up values in one column programmatically from android to excel

Tags: android, excel, sum, excel-formula, apache-poi

When I try to summing up the values in one such column it gives me 0 rather than summing it up.

Then I open in phone the value of sum shows 0.

If i open it in PC then it will show the original sum value done by Microsoft Excel by itself. And then in Mobile the sum will be shown 0 and in PC the sum will be shown as 280 (which is required..!!). So need solution when I open excel sheet in phone it should be perfect.

Here is the code,

```
package com.example.excelsheet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

    // Cell c = null;

    // Cell style for header row
    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
    cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
    cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    HSSFSheet firstSheet = wb.createSheet("MY FIRST SHEET");
    // HSSFSheet secondSheet = workbook.createSheet("MY SECOND SHEET");

    // HSSFRow row0 = firstSheet.createRow(0);
    // HSSFCell cell01 = row0.createCell(0);
    // cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("MY FIRST SHEET"));

    // HSSFRow rowB = secondSheet.createRow(0);
    // HSSFCell cellB = rowB.createCell(0);
    // cellB.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("MY SECOND SHEET"));

    // cell = row.createCell(0);

    int idxr = 0;
    int idyc = 0;

    Cell c = null;

    Row row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("RUTURAJ Raval");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);


    idxr = idxr + 2;
    idyc = 0;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Grand Total Sheet from receipt list");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);

    idxr = idxr + 2;
    idyc = 0;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Total is:");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("280");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);

    idyc++;

    idxr = idxr + 2;
    idyc = 0;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Sr no.");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);
    firstSheet.setColumnWidth(idyc, (10 * 500));

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Receipt Name");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);
    firstSheet.setColumnWidth(idyc, (10 * 500));

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Receipt Total");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);
    firstSheet.setColumnWidth(idyc, (10 * 500));

    idyc++;

    idxr = idxr + 1;
    idyc = 0;

    int firstRow = idxr + 1;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("1");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Maheshwari");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt("10"));

    idyc++;

    idxr = idxr + 1;
    idyc = 0;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("2");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Arihant");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt("20"));

    idyc++;

    idxr = idxr + 1;
    idyc = 0;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("3");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Hakim Chichi Sons");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt("30"));

    idyc++;

    idxr = idxr + 1;
    idyc = 0;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("4");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("D-Mart");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt("40"));

    idyc++;

    idxr = idxr + 1;
    idyc = 0;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("5");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Dhiraj Sons");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt("50"));

    idyc++;

    idxr = idxr + 1;
    idyc = 0;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("6");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Big Bazar");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt("60"));

    idyc++;

    idxr = idxr + 1;
    idyc = 0;

    int lastRow = idxr + 1;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("7");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Atul Bakery");

    idyc++;

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt("70"));

    idyc++;

    idxr = idxr + 1;
    idyc = 0;
    idyc = idyc + 1;

    row = firstSheet.createRow(idxr);
    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellValue("Total:");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);

    idyc++;

    // Dim rExternalTotal As Range , dExternalTotal as Double
    //
    // @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    // Set rExternalTotal = Range(rReportData.Offset(0, 0),
    // rReportData.Offset(261, 0).End(xlUp))
    // dExternalTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rExternalTotal)
    //
    // rExternalTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(columns("A:A"));

    String myFormula = "SUM(" + getColumnName(idyc) + firstRow + ":"
            + getColumnName(idyc) + lastRow + ")";

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
    c.setCellFormula(myFormula);
//      c.setCellValue("280 value");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);

//      firstSheet.groupRow(firstRow-1,lastRow-1);
//        firstSheet.setRowGroupCollapsed(firstRow-1, true);



    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/ExcelSheet/";
        File file_path;

        file_path = new File(path);

        if (!file_path.exists())
            file_path.mkdir();

        String fileName = "Excel_" + new Date().getTime() + ".xls";
        File file = new File(path, fileName);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        wb.write(fos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Generated",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}

private String getColumnName(int columnNumber) {

    String columnName = "";
    int dividend = columnNumber + 1;
    int modulus;

    while (dividend > 0) {
        modulus = (dividend - 1) % 26;
        columnName = (char) (65 + modulus) + columnName;
        dividend = (int) ((dividend - modulus) / 26);
    }

    return columnName;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Now my question is, what changes do I need to put?

Where am I getting wrong??

Please let me know..

Thank You..

Comment: And if I try to create as .xlsx then it shows error, so any solution regarding to that is also required..

Comment: Please first explain what you are creating in onCreate. Then tell what you are trying to summate. Then tell where you display or use the summation.

Comment: You don't appear to be evaluating the formulas. What happens if [you follow the POI docs on that](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) and do so?

Comment: Hello @GreenApps onCreate I am generating an excel sheet from my static data. I wan to sum up the last column of Receipt Total. I display at bottom of the list after 7 entries next to Total cell.

Comment: `it gives me 0 rather than summing it up`. Where/when do i/you see that 0?

Comment: Hello @Gangravarr let me check it.. thank u.. :)

Comment: hey @greenapps String myFormula = "SUM(" + getColumnName(idyc) + firstRow + ":"
            + getColumnName(idyc) + lastRow + ")";

    c = row.createCell(idyc);
    c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
    c.setCellFormula(myFormula);
//      c.setCellValue("280 value");
    c.setCellStyle(cs); here..

Comment: I still see no 0. So where did you see it?

Comment: hey @greenapps when I export it in excel and in device file directory if I check the created excel sheet it shows me 0 as a grand total.. but if u open that same excel sheet in windows pc or windows phone the sum will be 280 as it will automatically recalculate the function and will put 280 by that way.. but in android phone if u check excel sheet, it will show 0 as total.. I am using Polaris office viewer 5, updated version..

Comment: c.setCellFormula(myFormula); here from the myFormula syntax, the op should be 280 but it shows 0 in that particular cell..

Comment: Well that took you a long time to tell that basic info. You could have introduced your problem better than you did now. If you had started to tell that you programmamatically created an excel sheet with a summation formula in one of the cells and that the sheet did what you expected it to do on a PC but not on your Android device using Polaris office viewer your problem would have been clear.

Comment: I can confirm that your code creates an excel sheet that does execute a summation formula (Total: 280) on a PC or a Windows Phone but not on an Android device using Polaris viewer. You have excel sheets created on a PC where summation formulas do work on Android?

Comment: Tried it on a different Android device with Planmaker app. It displayed ok. Also Sheet To Go from Documents To Go app will display the 280. So will we blame Polaris viewer?

Comment: The thing is formula for summation works well, I just copy the excel sheet saved in android device to pc to check, whether it is right or wrong, but then as the formula is correct, in pc microsoft excel put the answer perfect after recalculation, but android is not able to do so, from summation formula.. And I have put formula which works for an android, as per http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/apache-poi-excel-row-group-collapse.html so no doubts could be there.. so if I have not put formula well in android then how after I copy to pc it gonna work well!!?? there I am not able to understand

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that your code creates an excel sheet with a summation formula which summates ok (Total: 280) on a PC or a Windows Phone but not on an Android device using Polaris viewer.

Tried it on different Android devices with Planmaker app. It displayed ok. Also Sheet To Go from Documents To Go app will display the 280.

So will we blame Polaris viewer? –

Comment: Yeah we should, but we must not blame them! So let me try in planmaker app from my android device and thanks a tone, for sharing your review! :)

Comment: Yes you were right.. I just check it in PlanMaker app, and total is perfect.. Something something is not well with Polaris app.. :D

Comment: And the answer is, everything is perfect in the code but the problem was with the Polaris Office Viewer 5, when I check in Plan Maker app, the excel sheet works perfect as windows pc.

So this is acceptable answer as a solution that something's wrong in Polaris, which I don't know, what is interruption.

But anyways, my required output was gained by this Plan Maker app.

Thanks all for sharing their reviews.. specially @greenapps..